# Mustachejs render html markup as html

Tags: mustache, html-rendering

We are converting an old CMS using Mustachejs.
The BODY of the content contains some html elements:

```
<strong>Mickey Mouse</strong> is a funny animal cartoon character created in 1928 by Walt Disney.
```

We we apply the value to Mustachejs like *{{Description}}*

The output rendered is

```
<strong>Mickey Mouse</strong> is a funny animal cartoon character
created in 1928 by Walt Disney.
```

Mustachejs literally displays the value as it is in the database.

How do we get Mustachejs to render the html markup as html?

**Desired Result**

**Mickey Mouse** is a funny animal cartoon character
    created in 1928 by Walt Disney.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not literally displaying the value as it is in the db, it's encoding it. It's actually outputting

```
&lt;strong&gt;Mickey Mouse&lt;/strong&gt;
```

Use {{{three_braces}}} to have Mustache render without html encoding the string. *{{{Description}}}*

Comment: Perfect ... so easy. Loving MustacheJS so far.

Comment: Note that when you use triple braces with user input, you should be careful to sanitize it before rendering.

Comment: And you should definitely do *whatever* @bobthecow says with regards to Mustache!

Comment: Lucky that I came across this answer. Though my problem is not related to this question, but I was really struggling to display &lt; and &gt; as '<' and '>' respectively. Used three_braces and it worked like charm. Answer upvoted!